# Terminating the loop in the shelf problem

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I'm currently doing the shelf problem (fairly well-known, I hope?). Essentially, I am given the scenario of a shelf (set) of blocks (elements), and I am supposed to rearrange them according to their size. This is part of an introduction to insertion sort.

The first part of this problem involves me writing a function `insert_animation(block_pos, shelf, high)`. This function takes in a shelf of blocks of varying sizes, for example, `[Block size: 2, Block size: 6, Block size: 1, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]`. I am given the functions `shelf.insert(position, block)`, which inserts a block at a given position, and `shelf.pop(position)`, which removes an element at position.

For this problem, I am supposed to first pop the element at the index (integer) block_pos from the shelf, compare the popped element with each element within the range from 0 to `high`, then insert the popped element just before an element with equal or larger value. If there is no such value (i.e. the popped element is bigger than everything), the popped element will be inserted at the position of `high` (i.e. the last position of the range).

I suppose I understand the logic, and have come up with such a code:

```
def insert_animate(block_pos, shelf, high):
    if block_pos == 0:
        return shelf
    p = shelf.pop(block_pos)
    for i in range(high):
        if p.size <= shelf[i].size:
            shelf.insert(i, p)
            break
        else:
            shelf.insert(high, p)
    return shelf
```

To my frustration, it seems as if the "break" statement just refuses to do what I say, and more and more elements keep getting inserted in.

For example, let `s = [Block size: 2, Block size: 6, Block size: 1, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]` (this is a code that requires a programme given by professors to run, and will not work on Python alone).

Suppose now I want `print(insert_animate(3, s, 3))`. I would expect

```
[Block size: 2, Block size: 4, Block size: 6, Block size: 1, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]
```

where the block of size 4 is popped and inserted just before block of size 6. Reasonable, I hope?

But with my code above, I get

```
[Block size: 2, Block size: 4, Block size: 6, Block size: 1, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]
```

The problem, as it seems to me, is that the `break` just isn't working, and the `for i in range(high)`
loop simply keeps running and keeps inserting the block of size 4 whenever the condition is met.

I've been cracking my head over this for hours today but can't figure out a way around it. This is just the tip of the iceberg of all my problems subsequently, but I figured this is the root of the issue, so if anyone can offer any advice on this particular matter, I would really appreciate it!!!

Comment: What does ``s = [Block size: 2, Block size: 6, Block size: 1, Block size: 4, Block size: 8, Block size: 3, Block size: 9]`` mean? It is not valid Python code. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve], i.e. provide the input as valid code.

Comment: Did you intend to have the ``else: shelf.insert(high, p)`` as part of the ``for`` instead of the ``if``, perhaps? Right now, it may insert ``p`` at ``high`` up to ``high`` times.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your reply. The original code provided is <s = shelf.init_shelf((2, 6, 1, 4, 8, 3, 9))>. I believe this code is not able to run on Python itself unless the module (which the professor sent us) is imported. I am unsure if I can upload the module file here, hence my deepest apologies that I have no provided the minimal reproducible example. If there is any way to offer the file, I will be more than happy to do it.

Comment: What it represent is essentially the list of elements (blocks) within the shelt (set). The number correspond to the "size" of each block The assignment is deliberately designed such that we cannot iterate over it like usual integers or strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Use `for:...else:` with nested `if:`, instead of `for:` with a nested `if:...else:`. The `else:` clause of a `for` loop triggers only if no `break` was executed in the loop – this corresponds to having found no valid position, thus needing to insert the element at the end.

---

The code currently insert `p` *for every element that is not smaller*, until a smaller one is found:

```py
def insert_animate(block_pos, shelf, high):
    if block_pos == 0:
        return shelf
    p = shelf.pop(block_pos)
    for i in range(high):
        if p.size <= shelf[i].size:
            shelf.insert(i, p)
            break   # stop once smaller element is found
        else:       # triggers *for each i* with p.size > shelf[i].size
            shelf.insert(high, p)  # insert until loop is stopped
    return shelf
```

Change it to trigger only if *all elements* are not smaller:

```py
def insert_animate(block_pos, shelf, high):
    if block_pos == 0:
        return shelf
    p = shelf.pop(block_pos)
    for i in range(high):
        if p.size <= shelf[i].size:
            shelf.insert(i, p)
            break
    else:  # triggers *for all i* with p.size > shelf[i].size
        shelf.insert(high, p)  # insert at most once
    return shelf
```

Comment: This is what I need! Thank you so much. And oh my, I didn't know of the for-else loop! :p Now I understand the logic. Thank you so much!